# QEMU Exception Handling

Tags: exception, x86, kernel, qemu

I ran into an error when testing some code that would generate protection faults. I had my exception handler setup so that it expected the EIP and Stack not to change, standard behavior on native CPU. But on QEMU both the ESP and EIP are changed at fault generation time.

The OS is 32-bit, so the error case is related to jumps out of the CS segment.
Digging into the QEMU code, it seems though the EIP and ESP are set after raise_exception_error is called within helper_ret_protected. So, I am at a loss to understand why I am seeing a different behavior in the guest.

Am I not understanding how QEMU generates exceptions, is there another step that occurs after ret_protected methods are called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon exception the CPU will switch stack when crossing privilege level boundaries.
The *[TSS](http://wiki.osdev.org/Task_State_Segment)* therefore contains `SS` and `ESP` entries for each level. If the code that triggers the fault happens to be in user-mode code, the stack will be changed.
The `SS:ESP` values are read from the `ss0` and `ebp0` fields of the TSS.

I'm pretty much not sure about what you mean by "expecting `EIP` not to change".

If you could give more details about your problem might help finding the correct answer...

Comment: the code allocates a large CS and then performs a Ret that lands it outside the CS. This triggers a general protection fault, as the code has exceeded the CS limit. In a native CPU when a GPF is triggered EIP will point to the faulting instruction within the CS. So, within the exception handler you can get to the faulting instruction, on QEMU, the EIP is outside the CS and does not point to the faulting instruction. Is that clearer ?

Comment: @anandb Much clearer. Thanks! Anyways, is there a reason you chose not to use flat segments? Did you test on bare metal? How about debugging (especially checking stacks)? Is the `ret` instruction in question related to switching to *PMode*?

Comment: BTW, if I remember well, `EIP` on the exception stack would not point to the `ret` that drove control out of `CS`, but rather the actual faulting address - that is out of `CS`, so unless I misunderstood you, the behaviour seems to be correct to me.

Comment: Isn't the faulting address the one of the instruction generating the fault within the CS ?

Comment: @anandb I think it is rather the address where the exception actually happens, i.e. outside CS - that's why the exception is triggered. if you have access to a machine with a floppy drive and a floppy disk, then it is quite trivial to find out: boot your code from the (flat) floppy and print the stack upon GPF. I think it'd print the address outside CS. Sorry for not being sure, I did these things quite some time ago...